# How to show Toolbar Title from Firebase Database with Category? I am stuck

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-toolbar

I am making an android app where show text from the Firebase Realtime Database into recyclerview with category, means in my app start with a different category and when the user clicks in any particular  category it opens a new Activity  where all data shown in a specific category, here is all fine. Now I want to set TollBar title with the category name that is stored in the Firebase Realtime Database, I tried some methods but all of the methods does not works, can anyone help me to achieve this?

*So when user click in any category it opens a new activity and toolbar changed in **every category**.*

**This is my Firebase Realtime Database structure**

[image: This is my Firebase Realtime Database structure]

**This is my Activity Class**

```
private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<QuotesItem> myOption;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<QuotesItem, QuotesViewHolder> myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_quotes);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myDetailsQuotes);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyApp").child("MyQuotes")
            .orderByChild("categoryid").equalTo(Utils.CATEGORY_ID);
    myOption = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<QuotesItem>()
            .setQuery(query, QuotesItem.class).build();

    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
    dialog.show();

    myAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<QuotesItem, QuotesViewHolder>(myOption) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final QuotesViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final QuotesItem model) {

            holder.mtextView.setText(model.getQuote());
            dialog.dismiss();
            setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public QuotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_quotes_item, parent, false);

            return new QuotesViewHolder(view);
        }
    };

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myAdapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to show the title? You need help with that?

Comment: Use getSupportActionBar().setTitle(.....)